# Error when made AngularJS $http request POST

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, jax-rs

I want to access POST method from my server, but when I logged the response, it's always return status=0, anyone can help me or give me an advise?
note: I've tried my method in Postman and it's works anyway

## This is my contorller

```
nameApp.controller('loginCtrl',  ['$scope','$location','Flash','$sessionStorage', '$cookieStore','$http',function (scope,location,Flash,sessionStorage,cookieStore,http) {

scope.nim='';
scope.pass='';
if(cookieStore.get('current')!=null){
    location.path('/homepage')
}
scope.login = function() {

    if((scope.nim=='')){
        Flash.create('danger', 'Invalid Username / Password', 'custom-class');
    }else{

        http.post('http://localhost:8084/iec3/rest/users/login',{'username':'admin','password':'bukanadmin'},{headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
               console.log("GREAT");
              }, function errorCallback(response) {
                console.log(response)
              });
    }
}
}]);
```

## This is login method from my controller

```
@Path("/login")
@POST
@Consumes(value = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(value = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response login(User user) {
    UserDao ud = new UserDao();
    User dariDB = ud.login(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword());
    dariDB.setPassword("");
    return Response.ok(dariDB)
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "origin, content-type, accept, authorization")
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD")
            .header("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1209600")
            .build();
}
```

## This Is the error when i try to logged the response

Object {data:null, status:0, headers:dd/<(), config:Object, statusText:""}

Comment: If you use the network developer tools, what response are you getting to that request? Are your headers being added to the response? What status code do you receive?

Comment: The response from the request is json, how to add the headers? The status code is 0, I don't know why it's return status 0 and the data is null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to verify if your request is reaching to the server. Is your login method is getting called? If you are on same host, there is no need to pass complete url, you can directly call your api via its path.

As for a newbie, I would recommend you to avoid `$http` shortcut methods. For better understanding and readability, you should use `$http` like

```
$http({
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'http://localhost:8084/iec3/rest/users/login',
  data: {
    username:'admin',
    password:'bukanadmin'
  },
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
  console.log("GREAT");
}, function errorCallback(response) {
  console.log(response)
});
```

Comment: I have tried to call the login method using POSTMAN,  and it's work well. Ah.. And i have tried that $http format, but nothing change..

Answer (score 0):

Your request from ajax does not seem to hit your controller method, status 0 is usually returned when the request is cancelled. Check the @path value in controller method and the http://localhost:8084/iec3/rest/users/login mapping.

For more details about status 0
http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-status-attribute

Comment: Okay, I'll try it, and how to make sure that my request hit the controller method,? I've tried on postman application for that url and method,  it's work well.. I'm fell confused now.. Thanks anyway

Comment: You can use curl as well to test restful API returning ,else change @post value to @path("/iec3/rest/users/login") . Details about curl http://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html